# How to convert DateTimeOffset back to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

When we create a search index and we define a field as DateTime the type is Edm.DateTimeOffset. And the value should be like this: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff[+|-]HH:mm`.

Now I have a file in my database of type DateTime that get's converted to Offset like this:

```
 DateTime offset = //get from database the date

 TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("FLE Standard Time");
 DateTimeOffset offsetConverted = new DateTimeOffset(offset, zone.GetUtcOffset(offset));
```

My question: how can I convert `offsetConverted` to my orginal DateTime `offset`?

Comment: What do you mean by "DateTime offset" exactly? A `DateTime` instance does _not_ store UTC offset part. It just have date and time parts (`Kind` also). Anyway, have you ever try to use `.DateTime`, `.LocalDateTime` or `.UtcDateTime` properties of your `offsetConverted`?

Comment: I mean: I have a DateTime in database: `2014-09-10 12:00:00.000` and I have to convert this DateTime to a DateTimeOffset that results into: `9/10/2014 09:00:00 AM` so what I need is to convert the DateTime back to original value.

Comment: @SonerGönül: I've use .DateTime but doesn't work. Now I tried .LocalDateTime and seams to work :)

Comment: @user2818430 It works on your machine running in your time zone, but will it work in other time zones? What time zone is assumed for the DateTimes that are stored in the database? As a rule of thumb, if you're storing DateTime values without the offset, you should assume UTC. Otherwise you lose information.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DateTime property of the DateTimeOffset class to convert the DateTimeOffset to a DateTime.

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflowProblem1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // input comes from user in form yyyyddMMTHHmmss
            DateTime offset = new DateTime(2016, 10, 12, 12, 22, 0);
            TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("FLE Standard Time");
            DateTimeOffset offsetConverted = new DateTimeOffset(offset, zone.GetUtcOffset(offset));
            DateTime roundTripOffset = offsetConverted.DateTime;
            Console.WriteLine("Input {0}, as DateTimeOffset {1},",
                  offset.ToString(),
                  offsetConverted.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("after round trip {0}, Kind {1}.",
                 roundTripOffset,
                 roundTripOffset.Kind);
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Input 10/12/2016 12:22:00, as DateTimeOffset 10/12/2016 12:22:00 +03:00,
after round trip 10/12/2016 12:22:00, Kind Unspecified.
```

Comment: You are using DateTime not DateTimeOffset as your input??